# My input in csv file was not recognised by R

Tags: r

I previously read string/factor column from csv file into R using multiplication symbol (×) and R recognised it. After my recent update, R stops recognising it. My previous code was

> read.csv("Histology4.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

I would to keep multiplication symbol (×) in my dataframe. Does anyone has any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

column in csv file

[image]

afer reading to R!

[image]

Regards

Comment: Can you upload the the data as I tried making a csv file with this kind of data and I was able to read it properly.

Comment: Try `read.csv("Histology4.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: Hi Shawn and Julien, it still get the same output (2Gy <d7> 5) aftering adding "encoding= "UTF-8". it worked okay with my previous R version. however, after I updated to 4.2.1, it gave me weird output. if you have any further suggestion, kindly suggest.

Comment: Sometimes accidentally saving a csv as an xlsx (and then resaving as a csv) will make significant but subtle changes to some data. I'm not sure if that could have happened here, but just leaving it as a note just in case.

Comment: Thanks, Stevec. have tried, but not worked. so weird!! Kind Regards

Comment: Dear all, I have solved it by reading excel file (xlsx) rather than reading csv file. i worked well. thank for your inputs. Regards